# Slice of opposite category equivalent to coslice of category?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be some category, and $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$.
We have the notions of the *slice category $\mathcal{C}/A$* whose objects are morphisms $A'\to A$ and the *coslice category $A/\mathcal{C}$* whose objects are morphisms $A\to A'$.

I am pretty sure that $$\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}/A\equiv A/\mathcal{C}$$ but I'm worried that I might have got an arrow the wrong way around at some point, and that the actual result is $$\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}/A\equiv (A/\mathcal{C})^{\mathrm{op}}.$$
The first one is what I hope to be true, since I would like it to be the case that a functor $$\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}/B\to \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}/A$$ gives a functor $$B/\mathcal{C}\to A/\mathcal{C}$$ and vice versa, but obviously (I hope) if the second statement is the true one then this functor will flip and be $A/\mathcal{C}\to B/\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slice and coslice categories in a category $C$ both admit a forgetful functor to $C$, which is one way to convince yourself that it's the second one: we have

$$C^{op}/c \cong (c/C)^{op}.$$

These categories both admit a forgetful functor to $C^{op}$.

But your hope is still fine: a functor $F : C^{op}/b \to C^{op}/a$ is the same thing as a functor $F : (b/C)^{op} \to (a/C)^{op}$, which is in turn the same thing as a functor $F^{op} : b/C \to a/C$. Taking opposite categories doesn't flip functors around (it flips natural transformations).

Comment: At least what I wanted to be true actually is true then, thank you!

Comment: Is there a name for this type of isomorphism? That is, the isomorphism between the two categories is, in a very loose sense, the 'identity' functor, and that just seems like quite a strong condition to have. Just wondering!

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: @QiaouchuYuan The more I think about it, me neither. Don't worry!

Answer (score 5):

Guess your out of luck indeed it is true that $(A/\mathcal C)^\text{op} \cong \mathcal C^\text{op}/A$

The isomorphism between these two categories is given by 
$$F \colon (A/\mathcal C)^\text{op} \to C^\text{op}/A$$

- where 
  $$F(f) = f$$ 
  for every $f \colon A \to X$ in $\mathcal C$
- and 
  $$F(\alpha)=\alpha$$ 
  for every $\alpha \colon f \to g$ in $(A/\mathcal C)[f,g]$, with $f \colon A \to X$ and $g \colon A \to Y$.

This functor is clearly well defined on objects because $f \colon A \to X$, that is an object of $A/\mathcal C$, is also an object of $\mathcal C^\text{op}/A$.

On the other hand if $\alpha \in (A/\mathcal C)[f,g]$, with $f \colon A \to X$ and $g \colon A \to Y$ in $\mathcal C$, then $\alpha \colon X \to Y$ and $g=\alpha\circ f$ in $\mathcal C$.
From this, since 
$$g=\alpha\circ f=f \circ^\text{op} \alpha$$ 
it follows that $\alpha \in (\mathcal C^\text{op}/A)[g,f]$ (this shows that the map is contravariant, that is that $F$ is a map from the graph $(A/\mathcal C)^\text{op}$ to $\mathcal C^\text{op}/A$).

Functoriality follows by simple computations and this is an isomorphism since it is bijective both on the objects and the morphisms.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer!

Comment: @Tim your welcome :)